# LoopThrough function skipping files

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to the site and in need of some help.  I've created a Macro within excel to pull the values from certain cells in workbooks within a folder and consolidate that information.  The code seems to be working, Except that it's only pulling from about half of the workbooks in the folder.  Does anyone know Why it's doing this and how I can fix it?

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
  Dim MyFile As String
  Dim erow
  Dim Filepath As String
  Filepath = "T:\Sales Orders\2017\May\"
  MyFile = Dir("T:\Sales Orders\2017\May\")

  Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "maytt.xlsm" Then
      Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open ("T:\Sales Orders\2017\May\" & MyFile)
    Range("F1:F7").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    ecolumn = Sheet1.Cells(Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Column


    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Summary").Range(Cells(1, ecolumn), Cells(7, ecolumn))

    MyFile = Dir
  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it only pulling from files with names starting with the letters "A" to "L"?

Comment: You might think about putting a file mask so that you are only dealing with workbooks (e.g. `MyFile = Dir("T:\Sales Orders\2017\May\*.xl*")`). Windows will put system files like `thumbs.db` that will really foul up a loop like yours.

Comment: YowE3K - No, there doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to the files that get skipped.

Comment: Jeeped - Thanks for the tip!  All the files in this folder are excel workbooks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to *skip* the file `"maytt.xlsm"` but what you are actually doing is stopping the whole thing (`Then Exit Sub`) when that file is reached. To skip the file and continue, do the following modifications to the code:

1- Add a line label before the `myFile = Dir` statement:

```
NextFile: ' <---------Add this
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
```

2- Replace `Exit Sub` with `Goto NextFile`.

Comment: Thank you!  I've tried this, but now the macro just wants to run through the files indefinitely.  Any ideas?

Comment: @L.Oldenburg did you place the label `NextFile:` **before** the line `MyFile = Dir` ?

Comment: Here's what I did:Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String
Filepath = "T:\Sales Orders\2017\May\"
NextFile:
MyFile = Dir("T:\Sales Orders\2017\May\")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "maytt.xlsm" Then
GoTo NextFile
End If

Workbooks.Open ("T:\Sales Orders\2017\May\" & MyFile)
Range("F1:F7").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

ecolumn = Sheet1.Cells(Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Column


ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Summary").Range(Cells(1, ecolumn), Cells(7, ecolumn))
 
MyFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub

Comment: As it turns out though, I was mistaken previously.  The code is still skipping about half of the files in my folder, but now it starts over again when it reaches the end (pulling the same files).

Comment: I have the "NextFile:" on the line directly above "MyFile = Dir"